# Delete text starting from a determinated string

Tags: text-processing, sed

For example, if a have the following text in a file on my Linux system:

```
10-02-2020
given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN. By default, grep prints the matching lines.
In addition, two variant programs egrep and fgrep are available. egrep is the same as grep -E. fgrep is the same as grep -F
16-02-2020
The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running
       system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list
       of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.
       The types of system summary information shown and the types, order
       and size of information displayed for processes are all user
       configurable and that configuration can be made persistent across
       restarts.
```

How can I delete all text before `16-02-2020` and turn the file into this:

```
16-02-2020
The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running
       system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list
       of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.
       The types of system summary information shown and the types, order
       and size of information displayed for processes are all user
       configurable and that configuration can be made persistent across
       restarts.
```

Comment: actually is before, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `sed`. The general format is:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' file
```

The `-n` causes `sed` not to print unless explicitly told to with `p`. Som that command will print all lines that fall between a line matching `pattern1` and one matching `pattern2` (inclusive). If there are multiple matches, multiple lines will be printed.

In your case, you want to print everything until the end of the file, so `pattern2` will be `$`. Therefore, you're looking for this:

```
$ sed -n '/16-02-2020/,$p' file
16-02-2020
The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running
   system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list
   of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.
   The types of system summary information shown and the types, order
   and size of information displayed for processes are all user
   configurable and that configuration can be made persistent across
   restarts.
```

---

On an unrelated note, `fgrep` and `egrep` are deprecated, you should use `grep -F` and `grep -E`. See `man grep`:

> In addition, the variant programs egrep  and  fgrep  are  the  same 
>   as    grep -E  and grep -F, respectively.  These variants are
>   deprecated, but    are provided for backward compatibility.

Comment: Hey there, I've tested here and it works, but can I edit your edit your answer to delete everything before and I aprove it?

Comment: @DaniloNeto already done. Please be careful next time though, as you can see this is now a very different solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot, worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Perl version :

```
perl -ne '$f=1 if /16-02-2020/; print if $f' file
```

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't specify that `16-02-2020` will always be the only text in the line, with no whitespace before or after. You might want to just use `perl -ne '$f=1 if /16-02-2020/; print if $f' file` instead.

Comment: Updated, but it could cause problem if `16-02-2020` happen to appear in the text before.

Answer (score 1):

For pruning a block from a file, I think `ed`, which treats the file as a whole instead of acting on a line at a time the way `sed` does is a better choice:

```
$ ed -s input.txt
1,/^16-02-2020/-1d
wq
$ cat input.txt
16-02-2020
The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running
       system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list
       of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.
       The types of system summary information shown and the types, order
       and size of information displayed for processes are all user
       configurable and that configuration can be made persistent across
       restarts.
```

Deletes everything from the first line to the line before the one starting with `16-02-2020` and saves the modified file. If used in a script you can use a heredoc to send commands to `ed`:

```
ed -s input.txt <<EOF
1,/^16-02-2020/-1d
w
EOF
```